# Right item of inline list covering text of left item

Tags: html, css

I have container with and image and text plus containers. I have a list of main containers aligned next to each other each containing an image and text. But somehow the z-alignment got messed up.

**The images are aligned next to each other with the right one oddly covering the text. I want the text to be in front of all images. How can I do so?**

In my version li is being created dynamically.

You'll exactly see what I mean running the snippet.

```css
ul {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}

.coverflow-images {
  padding: 0 12.5vw;
}

.coverflow-image:nth-child(odd) {
  width: calc(65vh*21/29.7);
  height: 65vh;
}

.coverflow-image:nth-child(even) {
  width: calc(55vh*21/29.7);
  height: 55vh;
}

li {
  pointer-events: none;
  will-change: transform;
}

.coverflow-image-title-container {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: inherit;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.coverflow-image-title {
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: font-size 1s ease;
  white-space: nowrap;
  pointer-events: auto;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.coverflow-image-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}


.coverflow-image-bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  pointer-events: none;
  will-change: transform, width, height;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: height 1s ease, width 1s ease, transform 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<ul class="coverflow-images">
  <li class="coverflow-image">

    <div class="coverflow-image-title-container">

    </div>
    <div class="coverflow-image-container">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQEP_259KLSzEG7_UQG-lzSlnEOPOFSQsPqXXT-GsDFeoqv8zGa&s" alt="Image" class="coverflow-image-bg">
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="coverflow-image">
    <div class="coverflow-image-title-container">
      <h1 class="coverflow-image-title">Why is the next image covering this?</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="coverflow-image-container">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQEP_259KLSzEG7_UQG-lzSlnEOPOFSQsPqXXT-GsDFeoqv8zGa&s" alt="Image" class="coverflow-image-bg">
    </div>

  </li>

  <li class="coverflow-image">
    <div class="coverflow-image-title-container">
    </div>
    <div class="coverflow-image-container">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQEP_259KLSzEG7_UQG-lzSlnEOPOFSQsPqXXT-GsDFeoqv8zGa&s" alt="Image" class="coverflow-image-bg">
    </div>

  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Brents answer below is what you need ....though so you can simply see what he means without adding js just add this: `.coverflow-image:nth-child(even) { z-index: 1;}` obviously the right approach is below... but so you can see the simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z-index` only works relative to siblings within the nearest ancestor with displays of: relative, absolute or fixed.

To fix your situation, you will have to use js to apply a class to the "current" `<li>` that you want to show on top. Then put it in your style sheet with a bigger z-index.

Applying some best practices and the adjustments...

HTML

```
<coverflow-images>
  <li>
    <h1></h1>
    <div class="coverflow-image-container">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQEP_259KLSzEG7_UQG-lzSlnEOPOFSQsPqXXT-GsDFeoqv8zGa&s" alt="Image" class="coverflow-image-bg">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="active"> // this indicates the current image
    <h1>Why is the next image covering this?</h1>
    <div class="coverflow-image-container">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQEP_259KLSzEG7_UQG-lzSlnEOPOFSQsPqXXT-GsDFeoqv8zGa&s" alt="Image" class="coverflow-image-bg">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h1></h1>
    <div class="coverflow-image-container">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQEP_259KLSzEG7_UQG-lzSlnEOPOFSQsPqXXT-GsDFeoqv8zGa&s" alt="Image" class="coverflow-image-bg">
    </div>
  </li>
</coverflow-images>
```

CSS

```
coverflow-images {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  padding: 0 12.5vw;
}

coverflow-images li {
  pointer-events: none;
  will-change: transform;
}

// magic
coverflow-images li.active {
  z-index: 1;
}

coverflow-images li:nth-child(odd) {
  width: calc(65vh*21/29.7);
  height: 65vh;
}

coverflow-images li:nth-child(even) {
  width: calc(55vh*21/29.7);
  height: 55vh;
}

coverflow-images h1 {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  line-height: 1;
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
  transition: font-size 1s ease;
  white-space: nowrap;
  pointer-events: auto;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

coverflow-images .coverflow-image-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

coverflow-images img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  pointer-events: none;
  will-change: transform, width, height;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: height 1s ease, width 1s ease, transform 1s ease;
}
```